# go application faasd run fail due to /root/resolv.conf unknown

Tags: go, openfaas

After a successful `go build`, when I try to launch `faasd up` in DEV mod it's unable to launch.
I was previously able to run the application with a successful go build. What could have happened?

```
Creating local directory: /var/lib/faasd/nats
2024/02/26 20:15:54 Running nats with user: "65534"
2024/02/26 20:15:56 Created container: nats
2024/02/26 20:16:00 Error creating task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/root/resolv.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/resolv.conf": stat /**root/resolv.conf: no such file or directory: unknown**
Error: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/root/resolv.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/resolv.conf": stat /root/resolv.conf: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Attempts I've made

- I restarted `faasd` and `faasd-provider`
- I rebooted the system
- I loaded the previously-working version of the application but it also failed to launch